# AWS beanstalk wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I was trying to setting up my AWS beanstalk by following the implementation guide provided by [AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html).

But when I got to the "Launch an Elastic Beanstalk Environment" section, this message appeared which basically said the app is not created.

Here's the message:

> [Instance: i-088472611e1ef4405] Command failed on instance. Return
>   code: 1 Output: ln: failed to create symbolic link
>   'wp-content/uploads': No such file or directory. container_command
>   2link in wordpress-beanstalk/.ebextensions/efs-mount.config failed.
>   For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB
>   CLI.

Does anyone have the same problem or know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the efs-mount to read the following, the directory clearly doesn't exist so lets just create it.

```
container_commands:
  1chown:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp /wpfiles"
  2create:
    command: "sudo -u webapp mkdir -p wp-content/uploads"
  3link:
    command: "sudo -u webapp ln -s /wpfiles wp-content/uploads"
```

2create will create the directory owned by the webapp user and should let you continue.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue. I am going to assume deploying via the AWS console. That is how I started.

STEP 1: I checked if there was an actual directory **wp-content/uploads** in **wordpress-beanstalk** and there was not. *It might get created on the first WP upload* So, I created the folder, rezipped the application, and deployed to Beanstalk via the AWS Console.

*I still received the same error and moved on to step 2*

STEP 2: Run EB DEPLOY from the command line
from my local **wordpress-beanstalk** directory

- > eb init
  >
  > - choose region (if you already created your app should be this region)
  > - if you already created application choose that ***wordpress-beanstalk*** for example
- > eb use *name of your environment*
- > eb deploy

I am not certain that Step 1 is related to Step 2, but was able to successfully deploy facing the same issue using EB CLI.

Answer (score 0):

This is the mounting error of EFS . 
EB is using EFS storage to store the wordpress files .

Please check the no.7 in documentation .

"Modify the configuration files in the .ebextensions folder **with the IDs of your default VPC  and subnets**, and your public IP address."

Please edit the **efs-create.config** file inside the .ebextension folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit late here so for anyone else having this issue, it's caused when that directory does not exist. Here are some reasons this might happen:

**1). WP has not created it** - Check manually that it exists.

**2). .gitignore** - When a .ebignore file is not present, EB uses your .gitignore instead. This can cause the directory to not be uploaded with the EB deploy command. If this is the case, make a .ebignore, EB will start ignoring the .gitignore

**3). Document root** - If you have modified the document root, to something like /src you have to modify the efs-mount.config file.

```
##############################################
#### Do not modify values below this line ####
##############################################
container_commands:
  1chown:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp /wpfiles"
  2link:
    command: "sudo -u webapp ln -s /wpfiles src/wp-content/uploads"
```

Even though the file mentions not to modify it, you have to add your document root path in the 2link entry. Change wp-content/uploads to src/wp-content/uploads (replace src with your document root)

Finally, I would not include a command to automatically make this directory, as that only puts a band-aid on the problem.

Hope this helps